# Set selected Text to JComboBox

Tags: java, jcombobox

Sample code:

```java
yesNoBoxRem.addActionListener(this);
if(e.getSource() == yesNoBoxRem)
    {
        if(yesNoBoxRem.equals("OFF"))
            {
                yesNoBoxSenMang.setSelectedItem("OFF");
                yesNoBoxMangDir.setSelectedItem("OFF");
            }
    }
```

Here, I am using 3 JComboBox with ON and OFF options,  How to set the 2 and 3 comboBox to OFF when First comboBox is OFF? I tried the above way but no result

Comment: the comboBox are not set to OFF

Comment: Were the values in the comboboxes String typed or custom classes?

Comment: they are custom values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(e.getSource() == yesNoBoxRem)
    {
        if(yesNoBoxRem.getSelectedItem() == "OFF")
            {
                yesNoBoxSenMang.setSelectedItem("OFF");
                yesNoBoxMangDir.setSelectedItem("OFF");
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
if(yesNoBoxRem.getSelectedItem()=="oFF")
    {
       yesNoBoxSenMang.setSelectedItem("OFF");
       yesNoBoxMangDir.setSelectedItem("OFF");
    }
```

Comment: Isn't equals method the preferred way to compare Strings?

Comment: Try to read the differance between the equas() and "==" from this linke:http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/java-questions/java-whats-the-difference-between-equals-and/ , but in this case the two way is correct :)

Comment: I dont know why it works only with ==, any way the code is working and I came to know the difference, thank u

Answer (score 2):

Use getSeletedItem() method instead of direct use of equals()

like below,

```
    if(e.getSource() == c1)
    {
        if(c1.getSelectedItem().equals("OFF"))
            {
                c2.setSelectedItem("OFF");
                c3.setSelectedItem("OFF");
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try to reapint those items yesNoBoxSenMang and yesNoBoxMangDir.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.Please give your answer clearly and Read the FAq before answering.